# How to drop rows based on values without dropping NA´s

Tags: r, sorting, na

I am trying to drop some rows from my dataset based on a few observations that i don´t want present in my dataset. I have tried doing this 2 different ways:
1:

```
   ALLdataCorrect <- ALLdata[ALLdata$`NACE Rev. 2, 
   core code (4 digits)` != "3513",]
   ALLdataCorrect2 <- 
   ALLdataCorrect[ALLdataCorrect$`NACE Rev. 2, core 
   code (4 digits)` != "1910",]
```

2:

```
   df2<-ALLdata[!(ALLdata$`NACE Rev. 2, core code (4 
   digits)`=="3513" | ALLdata$`NACE Rev. 2, core code 
   (4 digits)`=="1910"),]
```

However, both of these methods seem to also drop NA´s from the column that I am using to drop 3513 and 1910. I do not want to drop NA-values. Does anyone know how to make sure that this does not happen while sorting the dataset?

Answer (score 0):

I think a lot of the trouble is the non-standard column name.

```
ALLdata <- data.frame(
  `NACE Rev. 2, core code ($ digits)` = c("3513","3513",NA,"1910","2200","2245",NA),
  bibblyboo = c(1:7)
)

names(ALLdata)[1] <- "NACE"

ALLdata[!ALLdata$NACE %in% c("3513","1910"),]
```

gives

```
  NACE bibblyboo
3 <NA>         3
5 2200         5
6 2245         6
7 <NA>         7
```